# What is a word for "one who solves problems with physicality"?

Tags: nouns

I'm looking for a word to describe a person who approaches problems with physicality, as opposed to intellectually.

I'm having a difficult time describing what it is that I want, as I'm not necessarily interested in words like "brute", which, to me, imply a certain degree of aggression or a lack of finesse.  This doesn't necessarily have to be an angry or oafish person.  Just one who solves problems physically rather than intellectually.

EDIT: I suppose I wasn't clear in my original phrasing, but I'm looking for a noun.  I did say I wanted a word to "describe a person", but what I mean is a word that means "one who approaches problems with physicality".

Comment: **Hands-On** is all I can think of.

Comment: The danger of requiring us to find an obscure noun, even if it exists is that no one will understand what you are talking about when you use it. If I state that "Abyginstanic" means exactly what you want, it remains useless to you to communicate with others.

Comment: I'm not necessarily looking for an obscure or difficult word. Would you say that virtuoso is an obscure word?  What about pugilist?  These are very specific nouns and to my knowledge, they haven't destroyed our ability to confer meaning to one another.  I would argue, rather, that they have enhanced it.

Comment: Would "mason" fit in.

Comment: How about "a muscles person" vs. "a brains person"?

Comment: The fact that no one can think of what you're looking for easily suggests that, if there is such a word, it's not common. English allows adjectives to be used as nouns in many cases, that's how we fill in these gaps.

Comment: Perhaps you could enlarge upon what you mean by "physicality". Taking action versus deep thinking? Or someone who doesn't bother to read the instructions and starts plugging things in and turning knobs and screws right away?

Comment: I don't see the difference between the two.  Turning knobs without thinking is taking action, is it not?  Also, I think you pretty much hit the nail on the head with your answer, other than gender-neutrality.  That's why I accepted "doer".

Comment: The distinction I had in mind was "decisive action" versus "let's-see-what-this-does" action" :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion sounds a little naive, but **doer** might be a word to consider.

For example, "I see myself as more of a *doer* than a thinker"

From [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doer)

> a person who actively does things instead of just thinking or talking about them

It doesn't necessarily mean that a doer only accomplishes things physically though, but I tend to think of a doer as someone who 'gets stuck in' and physically gets things done rather than just planning or thinking about it.

Comment: It does sound a bit naive, but it's not bad.  It's the best so far, anyway.  Accepted unless something better presents.  Thank you!

Comment: Because of the gender-neutrality requirement, I think "doer" is the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 2):

"Man of action" is the idiomatic expression.  Was Kierkegaard a "man of action"?

Comment: Very good, but I'd prefer a single-word and, most importantly, something gender-neutral.

Comment: Man-of-action, voilà.  :-) Can't help with the gender.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes **"Muscular"** is used in that sense.  "He preferred muscular solutions"

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear in the question, but I'm looking for a noun meaning "one who approaches problems physically".

Comment: Adjectives are used to describe subtle distinctions in nouns, rather than invent fifty million nouns.

Comment: Both have their place, in my humble opinion.  See my reply to your above comment.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, one who fixes, changes, or solves things using physicality might be called a " BULLY ", but the term "Brute" as in brute force, might work as well. That is only 1 permutation of your question however, because you may mean more like the person who is strong enough to open a tight pickle jar lid or brace a wall while it is being framed.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered "physical"? It is one of the antonyms for "intellectual"...

Comment: As on Oldcat's answer, I apologize if this wasn't clear from the question, but I'm looking for a noun.  Something that means "one who approaches problems physically".